# change file extention of JSON file in struts 2

Tags: json, struts2

My application has a mechanism in exporting and importing a json file. Exporting will happen after clicking a link. The exported file have a default ".action" extension since the link is mapped to an action.

How to change the file extension automatically to ".json" since importing requires ".json" extension?

Im using this result type

```
<result-type name="json" class="com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you submit a form and the values are mapped onto the object, when using the json plugin you return a json string for ajax use... if you are really sending a file or returning a file then the content of the file has little to do with the issue.

See here for downloading a file with struts2: [File download using Java, Struts 2 and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122490/file-download-using-java-struts-2-and-ajax)